# Why the sum function only shows individual result?

Tags: sql

Can you please help guide me why the sum() doesn't work as per below scripts?
by right, I should get 3 rows of result, each row are in same, but now the sum() columns only show individual result. This is confusing.

```
SELECT distinct
       month_yyyymm,         usge_type_cd,       bill_class_cd,       billed_unit_type_cd, trans_dt   trans_dt, point_target, point_origin, external_id svc_no, account_no,  rmng_oper,
       T3.desc_text country, 
       Sum(sec_unit)  sec_unit, 
       Sum(gross_amt) gross_amt,  
       Sum(rducn_amt)  rducn_amt, 
       Sum(discnt_amt)  discnt_amt
       FROM   T2
       LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.lookup_cd = T2.jurisd_cd AND T1.table_abbrev = 'JUDT'
       LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.desc_cd = T1.desc_cd
       where  month_yyyymm = 202105
and  account_no = '3030' and TRANS_DT LIKE '2021-05-03'
and external_id ='8121' and usge_type_cd IN ( 1286, 1262, 1261, 1281, 1260, 1510, 6030, 1263 )
GROUP  BY 
          month_yyyymm,        usge_type_cd,
       bill_class_cd,
       billed_unit_type_cd,
trans_dt, point_target, point_origin, external_id, account_no, rmng_oper, T3.desc_text
```

This is what I get now,

| svc_no | country | sec_unit | gross_amt | rducn_amt | discnt_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 81215070 | Hong Kong | 3G HK (3-3G) | 20 | 0.49 | 0 |
| 81215070 | Hong Kong | 3G HK (3-3G) | 2510 | 61.28 | 0 |
| 81215070 | Hong Kong | 3G HK (3-3G) | 11830 | 288.82 | 0 |

But what I want is

| svc_no | country | sec_unit | gross_amt | rducn_amt | discnt_amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 81215070 | Hong Kong | 3G HK (3-3G) | 14360 | 350.59 | 0 |
| 81215070 | Hong Kong | 3G HK (3-3G) | 14360 | 350.59 | 0 |
| 81215070 | Hong Kong | 3G HK (3-3G) | 14360 | 350.59 | 0 |

Comment: Please clear this: what you expect and what you get?

Comment: I don't understand Are you getting only one row or too many rows? In case you are getting too many: `GROUP BY month, usage_type` would mean "give me one result row per month and usage_type". `GROUP BY month, usage_type, bill_class, ..., desc_text` on the other hand means you want one row per month and usage_type and bill class, and ..., and description. Look at your rows, they will all differ in at least one of these columns. Applying `DISTINCT` makes no sense here at all, because `GROUP BY` makes your rows distinct already, as just described.

Comment: The SUM works per group, as specified by the GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

This is happening probably due to your group by, you are grouping by everything and if you are getting only one row of results is because everything is group. Properly select your grouping by.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you all for the advice!

Comment: @stevensun try remove all group by and adding them one by one to see the results

Comment: I understand if I selected less and group by less, then I can get the correct sum result.
but by now I have to select those fields in one round, it'll show errors if I don't group by them.
There is an existing query based on above logic, and that query has been set up as a view, I select all from that view based on the above where conditions, I  get three rows of data with the same sum value.
I need the same result as select all from that view, but the sum value is wrong, it's just individual value instead of sum.

Comment: @steven sun: What does "individual value" mean? Are you getting only *one* row (one individual value)? Or are you getting *many* rows (many individual values)? Please edit your request and show what you are getting and what you want to get instead like Saeed Esmaeelinejad asked you to do one hour ago. Such a request as yours is usualy answered properly within minutes when what you are asking is clear. Just add sample data (say five rows) and show the result the query produces and the result you want to get, so we all see what you are talking about.

Comment: Hi Thorsten,

This is what I get now, you can see the sum doesn't work.
|svc_no |country |sec_unit |gross_amt |rducn_amt |discnt_amt|
|-------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|----------------------
|81215070 |Hong Kong - Hutchison |3G HK (3-3G) |20 |0.49 |0 |-0.49|
|81215070 |Hong Kong - Hutchison |3G HK (3-3G) |2510 |61.28 |0 |-61.28|
|81215070 |Hong Kong - Hutchison |3G HK (3-3G) |11830 |288.82 |0 |-288.82|

Comment: I've shared some sample data, not sure if you can see above.

Comment: Individual means that sum function does not work, those values are still the one without sum.

Comment: @stevensun can you send your raw data set? and by what you mentioned in your  data. set which is quite unclear. The expected result that you are showing if you want to achieve this by group , you should be getting only one row on information

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the *totals* from all rows summed together on each row.  For that, combine window functions with aggregation.  Instead of:

```
   Sum(sec_unit)  sec_unit, 
   Sum(gross_amt) gross_amt,  
   Sum(rducn_amt)  rducn_amt, 
   Sum(discnt_amt)  discnt_amt
```

Use:

```
   sum(sum(sec_unit) over () as sec_unit, 
   sum(sum(gross_amt) over () as gross_amt,  
   sum(sum(rducn_amt) over () as rducn_amt, 
   sum(sum(discnt_amt) over () as discnt_amt
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,
Thanks for this,
I've tried below statement, but there is no change, it didn't sum up each rows, Can advise? THANKS.
   sum(sum(sec_unit) over () as sec_unit, 
   sum(sum(gross_amt) over () as gross_amt,  
   sum(sum(rducn_amt) over () as rducn_amt, 
   sum(sum(discnt_amt) over () as discnt_amt

Comment: @stevensun . . . That is very curious.  Those expressions should be summing all values returned by the query.